# 404 Error On Ajax Post

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new at web dev and am trying to get a post method to successfully run.

Here is my ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Controllers/AddPropertyData',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: null, //Maps the controller params
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() { alert('Success'); }
    });
```

I have also tried this call with the url as: "/AddPropertyData".
Here is the post method I am trying to call which currently does nothing but return the view (removed all functionality for testing).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPropertyData(){

        return View();
    }
```

Everything I've tried has resulted in a 404 error. I am using the new Visual Studio for Mac and I've noticed that some of the config files have weird default values. I have changed my Startup.cs file as such:

```
        app.MapHttpRoute(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

It used to be app.UseMVC or something along those lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What's the name of the controller?

Comment: Unless your controller is named `ControllersController`, it looks like you're posting to the wrong route.

Comment: Holy crap! I've been using the wrong controller name... Thanks Rui. Now I have a 500 error, progress!

Comment: 500 error means your code is crashing. Check the response tab on that network call and you should be able to see the exception message

Comment: Yep- thanks buddy. I really just had a 4+ hour brain fart when I didnt realize the name of the controller was different than the name of the file/containerfolder etc. Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error 404 which according to HTTP means Not Found. You probably on the wrong route which doesn't map to any resource.